# Range of $\frac{\cos\theta_1+\cdots+\cos\theta_{10}}{\sin\theta_1+\cdots+\sin\theta_{10}}$ given $\sin^2\theta_1+\cdots+\sin^2\theta_{10}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Given that for $ \theta_i \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$, where $1 \le i \le 10$ , $\sin^2\theta_1+\sin^2\theta_2+\cdots+\sin^2\theta_{10}=1$, find the minimum and maximum value of $$\dfrac{\cos \theta_1+\cos\theta_2+\cdots+\cos\theta_{10}}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\cdots+\sin\theta_{10}}$$

I tried using Cauchy Schwarz inequality which just gives $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin\theta_i \le \sqrt{10}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos \theta_i \le \sqrt{90}$ because $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10}\cos^2\theta_i =9$ but I don't think it would be helpful here.

Maybe some inequality can be applied by writing it as $$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta_i}}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin \theta_i}$$

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: As @AlbusDumbledore showed, the minimum is $3$, also if you are curious for equality condition, you must refer to <b>Power Mean Inequality</b> that used during proof, its equality occurs only in equalness of all $\sin$'s, since argument bounded to first quarter, there is only one solution, $\theta_i = \cot^{-1}(3).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method suggested by @Albus Dumbledore can be tweaked slightly to prove that the upper bound of the given expression is $9$. Note that, since $\theta_i \in \left[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$, $\cos(\theta_i) \geq 0$ and $\sin(\theta_i) \geq 0$. We will show that $\cos(\theta_i) \leq S_i$:

\begin{align}
\cos(\theta_i) \leq S_i & \iff \cos^2(\theta_i) \leq S_i^2 \\
& \iff \sum_{j \neq i} \sin^2(\theta_j) \leq \left( \sum_{j \neq i}  \sin(\theta_j) \right)^2
\end{align}
Which is obviously true.
Thus, $\dfrac{\cos \theta_1+\cos\theta_2+\cdots+\cos\theta_{10}}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\cdots+\sin\theta_{10}} \leq  \frac{S_1+S_2+S_3+\cdots+S_{10}}{\sin \theta_1+\sin \theta_2+\cdots+\sin \theta_{10}}=\boxed{9}$ . Equality holds when $\theta_1=\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \theta_2=...=\theta_n=0$, up to permutation.

Comment: +1 i cant believe  i was  almost there ,its really nice approach

Comment: Thanks! Credits to you for even thinking about applying Power-mean for the lower bound, to be honest. Would not even have thought of applying that in the first place.

Comment: Ah! I wish there was something called the collaborated answer feature in this site

Comment: Yep, that will be good, but unfortunately we do not have anything like that yet.

Comment: Even this approach i would not have thought of i was ,using mixed variables, convexity to prove the upper bound Crazy how my brain didnt think properly of a simpler method!

Comment: Ironically, you did manage to prove the more difficult part of the question, which was the lower bound. Very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 5):

**lower bound**:

Notice that $$\cos ^2 \theta_1=\sin^2 \theta_2+\sin^2 \theta_3+\cdots+\sin^2 \theta_{10}$$ similarly $$\cos^2 \theta_i=\sum_{j=1 \rightarrow 10 , j\neq i }\sin^2 \theta_j$$
$$S_i=\sum_{j=1\rightarrow 10,j\neq i} \sin \theta_i \tag {say}$$
thus by power mean inequality

$$\cos \theta_i\ge \sqrt{\frac{S_i^2}{9}}=\frac{S_i}{3}$$ Hence  $$\dfrac{\cos \theta_1+\cos\theta_2+\cdots+\cos\theta_{10}}{\sin\theta_1+\sin\theta_2+\cdots+\sin\theta_{10}}\ge \frac{S_1+S_2+S_3+\cdots+S_{10}}{3(\sin \theta_i+\sin \theta_2+\cdots+\sin \theta_{10})}=\boxed 3$$

**Upper bound**: see See Hai's beautiful proof!

Comment: Nice solution Professor (+1) :).

Comment: It was from a mock test, but there only minimum was asked, but here I asked for the maximum also...(just out of curiosity :p)

Comment: @LightYagami Oh i see ,normal methods don't seem to work so i asked ,are you preparing for JEE?

Comment: Yes, actually...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118690/discussion-between-light-yagami-and-albus-dumbledore).

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Polli solution :^)

Comment: @Buraian good gracious! you know malayalam!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I am from Kerela too Lol ( Live in the gulf though .. for now :P)

Comment: @Buraian which part of kerala thrissur??

Comment: Sent a dm through chat @AlbusDumbledore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119458/discussion-between-albus-dumbledore-and-light-yagami).

Comment: @LightYagami pls delete commenst such off topic dicussions incur wrath of moderators

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Have you given your paper? If not, when is it? I have given mine! It was really easy... mine was today shift 2...

Comment: @LightYagami yes it was easy ! but I think I messed up the integer type questions coming back homes i realise  a few calculation error

Comment: @LightYagami how much out of 300 do you expect

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Did you also give the same as mine? I don't know how much I will get but probably around 250... I haven't found out any mistakes yet...how much are you expecting?

Comment: @LightYagami 220-230 shift 2

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Have you calculated your marks from somewhere or just a guess?

Comment: @LightYagami it a  guess,I was expecting 256 after writing exam but then after seeing my silly errors i knew that i would lose more marks,The paper in my opinion had atleat 270 matks straight forward , I forgot t revise semiconductors

Comment: I feel I could have done better,I am hoping to improve in next attempt to get somewhere around 260

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Are you talking about that logic gates question? It was the only question I left in the whole paper....

Comment: From where did you see your errors? I also want to check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120130/discussion-between-light-yagami-and-albus-dumbledore).